# Python Retrieving all Groups from a domain using OAuth2

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api, google-groups-migration

Using PYTHON, To get all groups in a domain, in OAuth1 had a command like:

```
groupfeed = api(lambda: GROUPS_SERVICE.RetrieveAllGroups())
```

In OAuth2, will it be

`allGrps = client.groups().list(customer='my_company').execute()`

I am looking for the equivalent code to get ALL groups in a domain. Thanks for your help and attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 200 groups, the results will be paged and returned over multiple API calls. You need to keep retrieving pages until none are left:

```
all_groups = []
request = client.groups().list(customer='my_customer')
while True: # loop until no nextPageToken
  this_page = request.execute()
  if 'items' in this_page:
    all_groups += this_page['items']
  if 'nextPageToken' in this_page:
    request = client.groups().list(
      customer='my_customer',
      pageToken=this_page['nextPageToken'])
  else:
    break
```

also notice that it's my_customer, not my_company.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Appreciate it, Will try this.

Comment: I am interested only in the group names from this list. How do I retrieve just the groups?

Comment: @user1816974 the group names are part of the dictionaries in `items`. Just do `all_groups += [item['name'] for item in items]`. See https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_member_groups